# Angular-Wizard dynamic template path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wizard

Is it possible to provide dynamic value for template attribute?

I tried the below variations.

```
<div class="container form-wizard">
    <wizard on-finish="finishedWizard()" template="{{wizardTemplatePath}}">
```

variation #2

```
    <div class="container form-wizard">
    <wizard on-finish="finishedWizard()" template="wizardTemplatePath">
```

Reference
https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard